# Poisson/non-negative gaussian noise data augmentation in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, noise, data-augmentation

I'm using Keras to do some data augmentation before passing 'images' of energy distribution to a CNN. I would like to add some noise to the images, but this noise can't be less than 0.

The data is in a numpy array of shape (5000,29,29), and the code for the data augmentation is currently:

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip(), 
  keras.layers.GaussianNoise(1)
], name='DataAugm')
```

Is there a way to add either poissonian noise, which is obviously already non-negative, or gaussian noise with the negative values truncated to the data augmentation layer, or do I have to add it manually to the data before parsing it to the NN?

Edit: Following the advice given here: [How to add a noise with uniform distribution to input data in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58484545/how-to-add-a-noise-with-uniform-distribution-to-input-data-in-keras?rq=1)

I created a class like this:

```
class noiseLayer(keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self,mean):
        super(noiseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.mean = mean

    def call(self, input):

        mean = self.mean

        return input + np.random.poisson(mean)
```

And I add it to my data augmentation like this:

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip(),
  noiseLayer(mean = 1)(x)
], name='DataAugm')
```

But I get the error:
The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("noise_layer_8/Identity:0", shape=(None, 29, 29, 1), dtype=float32)

I don't understand why the class that's defined as a keras.layer isn't actually considered a layer.

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Edited a second time to remove the tf.keras, as I've read that the problem could be compatibility between tf.keras layers and keras layers, however I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

Following advice from youngseok jeon on the thread I linked to above, it seems the problem was the inclusion of (x).

Using instead:

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip(),
  noiseLayer(mean = 1)
], name='DataAugm')
```

the code runs without errors.